# IIS7 giving Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis, iis-7

I have an IIS7 application that is using the .net 4.0 framework. The application pool has the rights (read/write/execute) on the folder of the application and has (select/read/connect) rights to the Database. IIS7 accept the aspx files and everything seems fine int eh settings however i am getting a 404 error when I am calling ti from outside of the server.

When I go in the server and call the http://localhost link, i get this error

```
    Server Error in '/Phonebook/PhoneBook' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  
Description: An unhanded exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   PhoneBookApplication.DBUtils.Execute(SqlCommand command) +399
   PhoneBookApplication._Default.FillddlSearch() +156
   PhoneBookApplication._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +54
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3047




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

If I call a default-defaut.html file, it works, but not if I call the default-defaut.aspx. But in the daufault pages settings, both aspx and html are there.

Also, it seems to have something to do with the sql server, but I do not understand where to look to debug that

I have no idea what is doing this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method DBUtils.Execute seems to have an error. What do do you have on the page_load or any event before the page_load ?

Comment: it makes a select in a table, I tried it from my machine to teh database the server is using and it works fine. The class also does not ahve an error since I am using it for other applications that works fine

Comment: @Hugo check the parameters used. Their is one that is not correctly initialized. Maybe its a cookie that should exist but doesn't ? (cookies work with the domain name, so it would make sense it work on some envrionement. If you could pase the code, it would help.

Comment: Found it, the error was not the good one. It was a rights problem. The account under which the app runs did not ahve access to execute the stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly where the problem is:

Your line 399 of the DBUtils class has a bug:

```
PhoneBookApplication.DBUtils.Execute(SqlCommand command) +399
```

IIS is not the problem. If you are getting a 404 error is because you are not going to the correct URL.

Comment: I checked teh class and it does not, I ran the application from my local machine on the test database and there was no errors. It only gives me these errors when it is on the server. It gives me a 404 error when I call teh application from outside the server and the error on my post when I call it from the server.

Comment: @Hugo, a 404 error means that the Resource was not found (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) which means that if you see that error when you access your application from outside is because you are going to the wrong URL, not because your app is failing. Your application doesn't throw 404 errors, your web server does.

Comment: The URl is the right one, I tripple checked it. the proof is if I change the default.aspx to default.html, it returns the page instead of teh 404. Also,  even if I go in IIS, and do browse on the application, I get the error witht eh stackTrace that I posted above